# how a user is able to push on bitbucket private account without giving him access?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a BitBucket private repository (MyRepo). I have given **Write** permission of MyRepo to user abc@gmail.com.

I cloned MyRepo locally.

I have set **git config user.email abc@gmail** so I am able to push with this email.

Then I updated email to **git config user.email other@gmail**

Still, I am able push with other@gmail.com. Logically It should not happen because I have not given permission to other@gmail.com

Please Clarify why and how this is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git config user.email` is just for identifying the user of the commit. It has no relation with who can push to the remote repository. Git push is authorized by your ssh key or http authentication.

If you want to control who can push to the remote repository you have to manage it from there (Bitbucket) and remove the user from the repository.